# Check authorization policy inside the action controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Because of the API is shared with admin and user. So I want to check the policy inside the action if the user id not equal with the parameter.

To simplify, this application using jwt token as the access token. So as for now have 2 roles which it `User` and `Admin`. So I add policy based on claims for this roles. Here how I generate the policy in `startup.cs`

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthorizationPolicy(this IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options = >options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy = >policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaimTypes.UserManagement, "User", "Admin")));
    services.AddAuthorization(options = >options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy = >policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaimTypes.UserManagement, "Admin")));

    return services;
}
```

`UserOnly` allow both of roles. `RequireAdmin` for admin only.

Here is the current API I do for change the password

```cs
[HttpPost("{id}/change-password")]
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdmin")]
public async Task <IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] UserChangePasswordViewModel model) 
{
    
    //This authorize filter require admin.
    //But I also want allow user to access
    
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if (user == null) return BadRequest("User not found");
    
    //My business logic here

}
```

So I change to `UserOnly` which allow both of roles to access it

```cs
[HttpPost("{id}/change-password")]
[Authorize(Policy = "UserOnly")]
public async Task < IActionResult > ChangePassword([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] UserChangePasswordViewModel model) 
{
    var getCurrentUserId = _identityService.GetUserIdentity();
    
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if (user == null) return BadRequest("User not found");
    
    if(getCurrentUserId != id)
    {
        //Check if this user is admin
        if(!isAdmin) //<-- Here I want to check the policy
        {
            //Response 403 forbidden
            
        }
    }

    //My business logic here

}
```

But I not really sure how to check policy inside the action. Any better suggestion? or need to use `HttpContext.User` for find the claim and check the value?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a dynamic policy decision by taking a dependency in your controller on `IAuthorizationService` and calling the [`IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method. An example of some fictional controller:

```
private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

public MyController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService) 
{
    _authorizationService = authorizationService;
}

[HttpPost("{id}/protected-action")]
public async Task <IActionResult> SomeDynamicallyProtectedAction() 
{
    var isAdminEvaluationResult =
        await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, "RequireAdmin");

    if (!isAdminEvaluationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return Forbid();
    }

    // ...continue processing the request
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`User.IsInRole("Admin")`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26503189)

Comment: @FluffyKitten: Why isn’t this an answer? I’d prefer to see more detail and explanation, but the [`ComtrollerBase.User.IsInRole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole?view=netcore-3.1) method suggested is a way of evaluating the roles assigned to the principal in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @JeremyCaney It is a suggestion to try something. If they want the OP to try out something then that should be a comment. If this was intended as an answer then that should be made clear. An explanation would do that and certainly improve the answer to meet SO guidelines, but at the very least it should be framed as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is no need to call RequireAdmin policy again in the action method to check the user is admin or not.

You could directly get the CustomClaimTypes.UserManagement claim value from `User` in the action method. Then you could write some logic to check the user is admin or not.

More details about how to get the CustomClaimTypes.UserManagement claim value and check it ,you could refer to below codes:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        string role = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == CustomClaimTypes.UserManagement).Value;
        if (role != "Admin")
        {
            return Forbid();
        }
        return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });

    }
```

Result:

[image]